# Does "Folder Redirection" and "Drive-Mapping" CSE really require "Always wait for the network..." to be enabled?

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I understand that both "Folder Redirection" and "Drive-Mapping"-CSE require synchronous GPO processing. However both CSE's are working here without having to force the GP-Client to work synchronously by setting "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" to "Enable" (some warnings show up in the log and rsop, saying user needs to log on again etc... yada yada, we all know them well).

Now I am wondering if the GP-Client has some kind of logic built in that allows it to distinguish between CSE's that need sync or async processing and arranges them accordingly in the startup- and/or logon process. Or are this just old settings within my testing-profile that make this CSEs "appear" to work? I hope you get my point.

As we are facing very bad startup- and logon times I am wondering if I really have to *enforce* the GP-Client into synchronous processing mode by setting "Always wait for the network..." to "Enable" or if I can leave it unconfigured even when using folder redirection/drive-mapping CSE and accept the necessity of having to log in twice to make the changes appear?

Comment: `Does “Folder Redirection” and “Drive-Mapping” CSE really require “Always wait for the network…” to be enabled?` - Where did you read that it is required? Secondarily, if it's working without that setting being enabled then I guess that would be an indication that it isn't required, wouldn't it?

Comment: The process is detailed here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/jj573586(v=ws.11)

(Though we once observed that the initial moval of files upon enabling folder redirection happened in the background after the second logon. Anybody?)

Answer (score 0):

Thx for replying and clarifying, there are many misleading blogs out there in that respect. If you write a short answer I will accept it...

So we can choose between cholera and plague here:

1. Keep fast logon enabled (async) and accept the necessity of two (sometimes even three when talking about software installation) consecutive logons to make the changes appear which will result in complaining phone calls to our service desk.
2. Enforce synchronous mode and accept slow startup- and logon times, which we are currently trying to optimize, but with the advantage of only needing one logon (for first time users)
3. Manually redirecting the folders by changing `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders` accordingly which comes with the advantage of a fast logon but the disadvantage of not having data moved automatically around (more of an advantage IMHO) https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/10/folder-redirection-impacts-ux-breaks-applications/